# Write \n in text file php

Tags: php, file

I want to write `\r\n` in file, not for making new line but literal text. The line I want to write in the file is

```
To make a new line write \n in the end of the line
```

My php code is like this

```
$handle = fopen("a.txt","w+");
$text = "To make a new line write \r\n in the end of the line\r\n";
fwrite($handle, $text);
fclose($handle);
```

But it is writing

```
To make a new line write
in the end of the line
```

That `\r\n` is parsed as `newline`. How can I write that text in the file?

Comment: You asked for it to write to a new line. So you want to actually write `To make a new line write \r\n in the end of the line\r\n` in that file rather than write that on 2 lines?

Comment: `$text = "To make a new line write \\r\\n in the end of the line\r\n";`

Comment: @AbraCadaver What they have now should work, *sort of*. I can't see how escaping will fix this. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner They are seen as the escape sequence in double-quotes so you have to escape them https://3v4l.org/Zuktn

Comment: Ok thanks @AbraCadaver - Curious why they'd want to do that, kind of defeats the purpose in a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$text = 'To make a new line write \r\n in the end of the line'."\r\n";
```

As this chars are not parsed if they are between single quotes.

Or escape the `\` with `\\` if you must use double quotes.